# OpenCV: error: (-211:One of the arguments' values is out of range) The number of points in the view #0 is < 4 in function 'cvCalibrateCamera2Internal'

Tags: python, opencv, runtime-error

Why does this error occur:

`error: (-211:One of the arguments' values is out of range) The number of points in the view #0 is < 4 in function 'cvCalibrateCamera2Internal'`

If I run this piece of code:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

s = 100
n = 6
h = w = s

gray = np.random.randint(0, 255, (h, w), dtype=np.uint8)  # Random image
objpoints = np.random.randint(0, s, size=(n, 1, 3)).astype(np.float32)  # Random 'real world' points
imgpoints = objpoints[:, :, :2]  # Assume camera image is 1-to-1 mapping of top down view of real world points

ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1], None, None)
```

The number of points is clearly `6`, so not less than `4`. Is there someone willing and able to explain this to me?

Thanks in advance!

## Edit

Based on the answer of @Christoph Rackwitz I modified the above code such that it works. However, I encountered a gotcha which initially added to my confusion, see the comment in code.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

v = 3  # Multiple views
s = 100
n = 100
h = w = s

gray = np.random.randint(0, 255, (h, w), dtype=np.uint8)

objpoints = np.random.randint(0, s, size=(v, n, 3)).astype(np.float32)
objpoints[:, :, 2] = 0  # Planar coordinates
imgpoints = objpoints[:, :, :2]

ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(
    objpoints, 
    imgpoints.copy(),  # GOTCHA: function fails without this copy due to it being a view instead of a separate array 
    gray.shape[::-1], 
    None, 
    None
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know that this API takes a **list of** arrays. That's one array (in the list) for each "view"...

"Views" are pictures. You are allowed to have different objects in different views, hence it's asking for object points for each view, instead of assuming a single object in all views. You can have the same object in all views. Then you'd have to pass something like `[objpoints, objpoints, objpoints, ...]` (or `[objpoints] * nviews` in short) and `[imgpoints1, imgpoints2, imgpoints3, ...]`.

For your sample data, just pass `[objpoints], [imgpoints], ...` (one view, so one object points array and one image points array) and that'll make the API happy about *this* error.

The code you tried in your question would present *six views* (first dimension) to the API, with each containing *one* point (second dimension)...

Since your sample object points aren't *planar* (z=0 for all), it's *then* complaining that it wants an "initial intrinsic matrix". It won't complain if you give it planar object points.

---

As for the "gotcha": OpenCV has no problem with views as such, if they are **contiguous** in the innermost 1-2 dimensions. A copy ensures that, but a copy costs some effort, so don't copy without a real reason.

OpenCV's `cv::Mat` is less flexible than a numpy array. A numpy slice is generally no longer contiguous, meaning elements "in the slice" aren't immediately adjacent to each other in memory. Say you have `a = np.arange(10); b = a[::2]` then `b` points to the same memory as `a` ("is a view of"), but only every second element.

`cv::Mat` has provisions for a larger-than-width "row stride". However you can't have (non-trivial) strides between channels (third dimension) and I think you can't have strides between pixels.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this makes it a lot clearer for me. There is still one thing I do not get though: if the first dimension is the number of views, then why do I need to provide a list with one set of points per view? Is that not duplication? I would expect that it would be either a list of 2D arrays with points, or a 3D array with shape `(#views, #points, #dims)`. But now I have to provide the latter in a list..

Comment: the naming of things is confusing here, I grant you. (not a list but) a numpy array of shape `(#views, #points, #dims)` (one each passed as the object points "list" and image points "list") is _probably_ possible, but then all your views would have to have the _same_ number of points. if you're dealing with a checkerboard, that is probably the case. I say "probably" because I'd have to try this. OpenCV's Python/C++ mapping can be tolerant or strict, depending on the specific function that is being called.